# Telerik reporting report parameters

Tags: telerik

I have used report parameters in telerik where in the parameter gets a string value entered by user and then it is passed to data source. When I use such parameter and do not pass anything, blank string gets passed and data is displayed. I have used AllowBlank=false but then report gets rendered on page load. And I dont want report to be rendered on page load.

Comment: You are not giving enough information here to allow us to help you. Is it in a winform, asp, MVC, ? Which Report viewer are you using? Is the parameter passed with the embedded design report parameter or with a text box to the query?

Comment: The parameter is passed with embedded design parameter. It si a web form, and I am using Telerik report viewer.